# BCE0044: expecting EOF, found 'import'

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, error-handling

I'm using the Javascript version of Unity's ScoreManager script and when I originally first imported it into my Unity project, I had an error telling me

> error BCE0018 the name "text" does not denote a valid type ('not found'). Did you mean 'NUnit.Framework.Internal.Test'?

Someone had the same issue and it was suggested in the answers to try adding `import UnityEngine.UI;`. I tried that and it did fix the BCE0018 error, but now there's a brand new error and I'm not sure how to fix it. The new error is

> BCE0044 expecting EOF, found import.

I've done some research and other people had similar issues with `}` and `var`, but I've yet to see one regarding import. Thoughts? Here is a copy of the full script that I'm working with.

```
pragma strict


static var score : int; // The player's score.

private var text : Text;       // Reference to the Text component.

import UnityEngine.UI;

function Awake ()
{
    // Set up the reference.
    text = GetComponent (Text);

    // Reset the score.
    score = 0;
}

function Update ()
{
    // Set the displayed text to be the word "Score" followed by the score value.
    text.text = "Score: " + score;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing namespaces must be done at the very top of your file, so move `import UnityEngine.UI;` after `#pragma strict`

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code:

**1**.`pragma strict` should be `#pragma strict` . Notice the "#" before it.

**2**.As [Hellium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52086287/3785314) said in his answer, `import UnityEngine.UI;` is placed in the wrong place. This should be placed right after `#pragma strict` and before the rest of the code.

Note that you should stop using Javascript/Unityscript. It has been discontinued in Unity and the compiler will soon be removed too. You should be using C# by now.

Here is your new code:

```
#pragma strict

import UnityEngine.UI;

static var score : int; // The player's score.

private var text : Text;       // Reference to the Text component.

function Awake ()
{
    // Set up the reference.
    text = GetComponent (Text);

    // Reset the score.
    score = 0;
}


function Update ()
{
    // Set the displayed text to be the word "Score" followed by the score value.
    text.text = "Score: " + score;
}
```